# Is this a proper recursive call? Function calls itself, but Edx grader doesn't see it

Tags: python, recursion

My quite overly complex function (tested and works):

```
def lenRecur(aStr):
    '''
    aStr= a string
    return length of aStr
    '''
    lenn=1
    n=0
    def lenR(aStr,Lenn,n):
        if aStr[n+1: ] == '':
            return 1
        else:
            Lenn=Lenn + lenR(aStr[n+1:],Lenn,n)
            return Lenn
    return lenR(aStr, lenn, n)
```

In rejecting the code, the edX grader  asks me to use a recursive call, even though I believe I used recursion.

Here is their code:

```
def lenRecur(aStr):
    '''
    aStr: a string

    returns: int, the length of aStr
    '''
    # Base case: When aStr is the empty string,
    #  its length is zero.
    if aStr == '':
        return 0

    # Recursive case: If the string is not zero-length, then remove the first
    #  character and the length is 1 + the length of the rest of the string
    return 1 + lenRecur(aStr[1:])
```

Is the grader just wrong? I would also welcome any comments on which code is better and why (I suspect mine is not).

Thanks

Comment: Is your function called `lenRecur` or `lenR`? Your outer function is not recursive, your inner function is. I think that's what they test.

Comment: I guess that is it. lenRecur is the function.

Comment: So there's your answer - `lenRecur` is not calling itself, it's calling `lenR` which is recursive.

Answer (score 3):

Rather than taking some complex approach to determining "rercursiveness", the grader may simply be looking for `lenRecur(` to appear twice in your code. Although your inner function `lenR()` is recursive, the outer function isn't.

Also, your code incorrectly returns

```
lenRecur("") == 1
```

In terms of which is better, the fact that the exemplar achieves the correct result in only three lines, with no complex syntax, is a good sign in their favour. Your code does almost exactly the same thing, but in a more roundabout fashion. The fact that you never change `n` makes it a somewhat pointless variable, just confusing the matter (`aStr[n+1:]` is always just `aStr[1:]`).